# How do I resume an upgrade after pressing d for details in terminal?

Tags: command-line, upgrade

In upgrading Ubuntu using terminal, one may be confronted with questions concerning the removal of obsolete packages or whether one wants to keep current version of some file. The answer options for these questions are

```
Continue [yN]  Details [d]d
```

Pressing `d` for details, one receives a list of such, which may be advanced using the enter key. The list will end with a line saying `(END)`, after which one cannot advance further with the enter key.

From this point, how does one return to the upgrade process with out terminating it?

Comment: Did you change the file `/etc/default/rcS`? 
To get out, you can press "q".

Comment: No I didn't. Should I ? How do I do that?

Comment: I did this exact thing then hit ctrl... x or something and ended up back at the bash. Now I'm not sure how to get back to this session. :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a `less` session. Just press <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit and resume.

Comment: Thanks. Q did it. What should I press here?
Configuration file `/etc/default/rcS'
 ==> File on system created by you or by a script.
 ==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** rcS (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?

Comment: In your case, there seem to be quite a few differences. If this was a conscious change on your part, stick with your version (N) but if it's not, refresh back to the maintainer's version (Y/I).

Comment: Also, stop using 12.10. It's been dead for a while. You need to upgrade through to at least 14.04.

Comment: Saved my day.Thanks a lot